# Create percentage bar chart in Stata for categorical variables from R code

Tags: r, stata, categorical-data, summary

I'm new to Stata and trying to recreate my R code there. I have two factor variables I want to plot. One is expenses, and takes the values `"Afs 2500-5000"   "Afs 5000-7500"   "Afs 7500-10000"      "Less than Afs 2500" "More than Afs 10000"`.

The other one is education level, and takes the values `"High school"   "Madrassa"    "No schooling"    "Other"    "Primary school"   "Secondary school"`

To plot a bar chart with percentages, I used

```
educ <- with(data, table(expenses, education))
education <- round(prop.table(educ,2)*100,digits=0)
barplot(prop.table(education,2)*100,
        xlab='Education level',ylab='Percentages',main="Monthly expenses by education status",beside=T, col = ramp.list,
        legend=rownames(education), args.legend
        = list(x = "topleft", cex=0.3))
```

which gave me this: [percentage bar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmAFa.png)

How can I do the same in Stata? There seems to be no easy way to recode a variable like in R with as.factor. The closest I've got was this:

```
encode Education, generate(educ)
tabulate Expenditure educ, col
```

`table Expenditure, stat(fvpercent educ)` won't work.

What is the equivalent of as.factor in R and how can I generate visualisations like the one I presented above? Thanks!

Comment: There is zero need to declare a variable as factor in Stata for graphical purposes. Indeed, Stata's concept of factor variables doesn't match that of R beyond loosely. Post example data to get suggestions about how do this in Stata. As often here, what's a translation from L code to M code to do task X? is a less fruitful question from How to do X in M?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the absence of a data example:

Note first that your graph is messed up because the categories for both predictor and outcome are alphabetically (alphanumerically) ordered. For example, the expenses variable should start with `"Less than Afs 2500"` and the education variable should start at `"No schooling"` and follow with `"Primary School"`.

On the main question: in Stata you could use `graph bar` or any command that is a wrapper for that.

This example is reproducible:

```
sysuse auto, clear 

set scheme s1color 

ssc install catplot 

catplot rep78, over(foreign) percent(foreign) recast(bar) ///
asyvars bar(1, color(red)) bar(2, fcolor(red*0.4) lcolor(red)) ///
bar(3, fcolor(blue*0.2) lcolor(blue)) bar(4, fcolor(blue*0.6) lcolor(blue)) ///
bar(5, color(blue)) legend(row(1)) ytitle(% of Domestic or foreign) yla(, ang(h))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Also for the code example, I enjoyed playing with that graph a lot.